# I've broken the short code for Contact Form 7!

Tags: shortcode, plugin-contact-form-7

Well I should qualify that title. The shortcode is fine in itself, and no doubt nothing to do with the guys at CF7 causing this issue. I am sure it's me, but it just isn't working after I've added another shortcode directly after it. Here's the story:

I have a page which should appear with some text to non logged-in users, and then a submission form appears (on the same page) when the user is logged in. I used some code for this in my `functions.php` which looks like this:

```
add_shortcode( 'visitor', 'visitor_check_shortcode' );

function visitor_check_shortcode( $atts, $content = null ) {
     if ( ( !is_user_logged_in() && !is_null( $content ) ) || is_feed() )
        return $content;
    return '';
}

add_shortcode( 'member', 'member_check_shortcode' );

function member_check_shortcode( $atts, $content = null ) {
     if ( is_user_logged_in() && !is_null( $content ) && !is_feed() )
        return $content;
    return '';
}`
```

and then I have wrapped the appropriate text on the page with the shortcodes as follows:

```
[visitor]
the text that appears to non logged-in users
[/visitor]

[member]
the text that appears to logged-in users and this form:
[contact-form-7 id="26" title="Submit your work"]
[/member]
```

The problem is that with the `[/member]` shortcode in place, it disables the contact form 7 shortcode. So that it appears on the page exactly as it does above (i.e. a string of shortcode), and doesn't display the form. If I remove the `[/member]` shortcode, the contact form works again. But I need the `[/member]` shortcode! Any ideas what I've done wrong?

Comment: Don't forget to close your question if answered.

Answer (score 1):

From the [codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API):

> The shortcode parser uses a single pass on the post content. This
>   means that if the $content parameter of a shortcode handler contains
>   another shortcode, it won't be parsed.
>   http://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API

The codex also provides the solution to your issue, which is to use the funciton do_shortcode()

> If the enclosing shortcode is intended to permit other shortcodes in
>   its output, the handler function can call do_shortcode() recursively:

```
function caption_shortcode( $atts, $content = null ) {
   return '<span class="caption">' . do_shortcode($content) . '</span>';
}
```

So, in your case you would need to edit the members function to include the form shortcode in it. Probably something along these lines:

```
function member_check_shortcode( $atts, $content = null ) {
     if ( is_user_logged_in() && !is_null( $content ) && !is_feed() )
        return $content . do_shortcode([contact-form-7 id="26" title="Submit your work"]);
    return '';
}`
```

If you need to change the form ID or title on the fly, you could pass those parameters via the members shortcode.

Answer (score 0):

The comment from gdaniel is right on the money.  In order to handle nested shortcodes properly, you can wrap your `$content` with do_shortcode().

Your MEMBER handler would become:

```
function member_check_shortcode( $atts, $content = null ) {
 if ( is_user_logged_in() && !is_null( $content ) && !is_feed() )
    return do_shortcode($content);
return '';
```

}`